# Ordered list item bullet and container to text-bottom if contains inline-block child

Tags: html, css

The issue I am having is with text inside of a `ol li div` causing the bullet item to display at the bottom of the text item. The issue happens when any element inside the `li` has display set to inline-block.

```
ol li div { display: block; }

ol li div h3 { width: 85%; margin: 0px; display: inline-block; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xgmwac96/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `vertical-align: top;` to your `h3` element.

```
ol li div {
    display: block;
}
ol li div h3 {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;/* Added */
}
ol li div a {
    float: right;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/xgmwac96/3/)

Comment: Nifty. That seems to work. Thanks :) I was fairly confident I tried that at one point, but there it is.